# WNS Azure Push notifications toast is not working only tile

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-notificationhub, wns

We are using WNS Azure push notifications and on the app side we are registering 2 templates for a tile and for a toast (example below).

On some WP8.1 devices we are not receiving toast notifications, but only tile notifications. Also we saw that on these devices the app is not appearing in the Notification & action settings page.

```
var toast = ToastContentFactory.CreateToastText02();
toast.TextHeading.Text = "$(title)";
toast.TextBodyWrap.Text = "$(text)";
toast.Launch = PushArguments.GetTemplate();

var tileSquare = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150Text02();
tileSquare.TextHeading.Text = "$(title)";
tileSquare.TextBodyWrap.Text = "$(text)";

var tileWide = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWide310x150Text01();
tileWide.Square150x150Content = tileSquare;
tileSquare.RequireSquare71x71Content = false;
tileWide.TextHeading.Text = "$(title)";
tileWide.TextBody1.Text = "$(text)";

var res1 = await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(channel.Uri, toast.GetXml(), "toast", tags);
var res2 = await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(channel.Uri, tileWide.GetXml(), "tileWide", tags);
```